# Python ValueError: Too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I'm building a crawler to extract article titles & URLs. I tried running to code below but I get the error in the title. Is there a dictionary I need to define? What am I doing wrong?

```
def get_page(page):
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    html = urlopen(page).read()
    p = str(html, encoding='utf-8')
    return p

def get_next_target(page):
    start_link = page.find('title may-blank" href=')
    start_quote = page.find('"', start_link)
    end_quote = page.find ('"', start_quote + 1)
    url = page[start_quote+1:end_quote] # Gets Article URL
    start_title = page.find (">", end_quote)
    end_title = page.find ("<", start_title)
    title = page[start_title+1:end_title] # Gets Article Title
    return title, url, end_quote

def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            print("%s, %s" % (title, url))
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break

reddit_url = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews'

print(print_all_links(reddit_url))
```

Comment: Provide full traceback please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_next_target` function returns a tuple containing 3 elements but you're unpacking them to 2 variables. You'd do

```
title, url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, fixed it. But now when I run the Python file in the shell, I simply get "http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnew, http://www.reddit.com/r/worldnew
None". =(

Comment: @PhillipeDongwooHan, `print_all_links` implicitly returns None.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here (as the other already pointed out):

```
def print_all_links(page):
    while True:
        url, endpos = get_next_target(page)
        if url:
            print("%s, %s" % (title, url))
            page = page[endpos:]
        else:
            break
```

`get_next_target(page)` returns 3 elemens.

You need this

`title, url, endpos = get_next_target(page)`

instead of this

`url, endpos = get_next_target(page)`